# How can I animate a circle to move in a rectangular path in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, draw

I'm trying to animate a circle in opencv to move around the display screen in a rectangle path. Here's what I have so far. So far nothing is showing up when I run the program. I need help "erasing" the circle after it moves position. This is part of a larger program. I already have cv2, numpy and deque imported. Thanks!

```
circlex = int
circley = int
circlex == 600
circley == 400
while circley == 400:
    if 200 < circlex < 1000:
        cv2.circle(frame,(circlex,400),10,(112,204,84))
        cv2.waitKey(10)
        circlex = circlex + 1
while circlex == 1000:
    cv2.circle(frame, (1000, circley), 10, (112, 204, 84))
    cv2.waitKey(10)
    circley = circley + 1
while circley == 200:
    if 200 < circlex < 1000:
        cv2.circle(frame,(circlex,200),10,(112,204,84))
        cv2.waitKey(10)
        circlex = circlex - 1
while circlex == 200:
    cv2.circle(frame, (200, circley), 10, (112, 204, 84))
    cv2.waitKey(10)
    circley = circley - 1
```

Comment: circlex == 600
circley == 400 can we use assignment statements like this?Sir could you explain?

Comment: In the loop, you can copy `frame`, then draw circle if the only problem is that you want to erase the previous circle. Also, @AnshumanJayaprakash is right. You should use `=` for assignment, otherwise that line does nothing.